# How to publish the ID attribute from JSON to influx DB using JMETER

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing, grafana, influxdb

I have API which is returning a unique id in response.

I'm trying to run this service in JMETER with 100 thread count and ensuring the id return value.

**API:**

```
GET: https://localhost:8080/transaction?createRandomExpireQuotes=true
```

**Response Body:**

```
{
   "quotes_Id" :"Q82817Dwewiiao0@asdfs2Aas2fdsdfde"
}
```

I just have backend listener and configured InfluxDb and Also I extract the above quotes_id from the response.

But I'm trying to pass the above quotes_id to influx db and wanna display that values in Grafana dashboard as table format.

Is this possible? can someone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter is sending the [following metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) to InfluxDB:

```
15.1.1 Thread/Virtual Users metrics

Thread metrics are the following:

<rootMetricsPrefix>test.minAT
    Min active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.maxAT
    Max active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.meanAT
    Mean active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.startedT
    Started threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.endedT
    Finished threads

15.1.2 Response times metrics

Response related metrics are the following:

<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.count
    Number of successful responses for sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.h.count
    Server hits per seconds, this metric cumulates Sample Result and Sub results (if using Transaction Controller, "Generate parent sampler" should be unchecked)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.min
    Min response time for successful responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.max
    Max response time for successful responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.avg
    Average response time for successful responses of sampler name.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.pct<percentileValue>
    Percentile computed for successful responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each calculated value.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.count
    Number of failed responses for sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.min
    Min response time for failed responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.max
    Max response time for failed responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.avg
    Average response time for failed responses of sampler name.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.pct<percentileValue>
    Percentile computed for failed responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each calculated value.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.count
    Number of responses for sampler name (sum of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.sb.bytes
    Sent Bytes
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.rb.bytes
    Received Bytes
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.min
    Min response time for responses of sampler name (min of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.max
    Max response time for responses of sampler name (max of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.avg
    Average response time for responses of sampler name (avg of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.pct<percentileValue>
    Percentile computed for responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each calculated value. (calculated on the totals for OK and failed samples)
```

For sending anything apart from this you will need to either extend existing [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) implementations or [create your own listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-write-your-own-jmeter-listener-guide)